# Using mac fonts with enscript

Tags: fonts, enscript

I'm using GNU enscript on a MacBook pro

this command works
`enscript -G --line-numbers -f Helvetica@11 -p out1 file.txt`

I'd like to be able to use some of the
native mac fonts - is there a way to find the correct font name to use in the -f command line argument?

Comment: Kenneth H. East Post did more digging to similar question.  

Adding Fonts to enscript https://east.fm/posts/adding-fonts-to-enscript/index.html